# how to stop a loop before the calculation answer reaches a variable?

Tags: c++

Here's my code and i'm doing a program that tabulates distance ,time and velocity of a falling object based on the distance the user inputs. I want the loop to stop once it reaches maximum and then calculates the final distance, time and velocity

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
#define magnitute 9.81

int main(void)
{
    double initial_velocity = 0;
    int time = -1;
    double final_time;
    double distance;
    distance = 0;
    char direction;
    double velocity = 0;
    double total_distance = 0;
    double final_distance;
    double final_velocity;
    final_velocity = 0;

    cout << "Enter whether the object is thrown upwards or downwards" << endl;
    cout << "Enter U for upwards and D for downwards" << endl;
    cin >> direction;
    cout << "Enter the distance of the object and the ground" << endl;
    cin >> distance;
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "|" << setw(15) << "distance" << "|" << setw(15) << "time" << "|" << setw(15) << "Velocity" << "|" << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;

    while (direction == 'D' || direction == 'd' && total_distance <= distance )
    {
        if (total_distance <= distance) 
        {
            initial_velocity += magnitute;
            velocity = initial_velocity + (magnitute * time);
            time = time + 1;
            total_distance = (initial_velocity * time) + (1 / 2) * magnitute * time * time;
            cout << setw(10) << total_distance << setw(10) << time << setw(15) << velocity << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            final_distance = velocity * time + 1 / 2 * magnitute * time * time;
            final_time = final_distance / 2 / (0 + final_velocity);
            final_velocity = velocity + magnitute * time;
            cout << setw(10) << velocity << setw(10) << final_time << setw(15) << final_velocity;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your line :

> ```
> while (direction == 'D' || direction == 'd' && total_distance <= distance )
> ```

adding all the parenthesis is like :

```
while ((direction == 'D') || ((direction == 'd') && (total_distance <= distance )))
```

and this not what you wanted because if you enter 'D' you will never stop the loop, you wanted something like :

```
while ((direction == 'D' || direction == 'd') && (total_distance <= distance))`
```

even it was better to test *direction* before that loop because it never changes in it.

Now having the right test to have inside the  loop :

> ```
>  if (total_distance <= distance) 
>  {
>     ...
>  }
>  else
>  {
>     ...
>  }
> ```

has no sense because you know `if (total_distance <= distance)` is true, so if you want to  do the *else* part you have to put it after the loop, like :

```
if (direction == 'D' || direction == 'd') {
  while (total_distance <= distance )
  {
      initial_velocity += magnitute;
      velocity = initial_velocity + (magnitute * time);
      time = time + 1;
      total_distance = (initial_velocity * time) + (1 / 2) * magnitute * time * time;
      cout << setw(10) << total_distance << setw(10) << time << setw(15) << velocity << endl;
  }

  final_distance = velocity * time + 1 / 2 * magnitute * time * time;
  final_time = final_distance / 2 / (0 + final_velocity);
  final_velocity = velocity + magnitute * time;
  cout << setw(10) << velocity << setw(10) << final_time << setw(15) << final_velocity;
}
```

Note the values you write in the loop can be wrong because *total_distance* can be greater than *distance*, finally why that loop ?

The widths you use and separators are not consistent between the header and later, better to have the same.

So for instance :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

#define magnitute 9.81

int main(void)
{
    double initial_velocity = 0;
    int time = -1;
    double final_time;
    double distance;
    distance = 0;
    char direction;
    double velocity = 0;
    double total_distance = 0;
    double final_distance;
    double final_velocity;
    final_velocity = 0;

    cout << "Enter whether the object is thrown upwards or downwards" << endl;
    cout << "Enter U for upwards and D for downwards" << endl;
    cin >> direction;
    cout << "Enter the distance of the object and the ground" << endl;
    cin >> distance;
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "|" << setw(15) << "distance" << "|" << setw(15) << "time" << "|" << setw(15) << "Velocity" << "|" << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;

   if (direction == 'D' || direction == 'd') {
     while (total_distance <= distance )
     {
       initial_velocity += magnitute;
       velocity = initial_velocity + (magnitute * time);
       time = time + 1;
       total_distance = (initial_velocity * time) + (1 / 2) * magnitute * time * time;
       cout << "|" << setw(15) << total_distance << "|" << setw(15) << time << "|" << setw(15) << velocity << "|" << endl;
     }
     
     final_distance = velocity * time + 1 / 2 * magnitute * time * time;
     final_time = final_distance / 2 / (0 + final_velocity);
     final_velocity = velocity + magnitute * time;
     cout << "|" << setw(15) << velocity << "|" << setw(15) << final_time << "|" << setw(15) << final_velocity << "|" << endl;
   } 
    
   return 0;
}
```

Compilation and executions:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -Wall c.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter whether the object is thrown upwards or downwards
Enter U for upwards and D for downwards
D
Enter the distance of the object and the ground
10
------------------------------------------------------------------
|       distance|           time|       Velocity|
------------------------------------------------------------------
|              0|              0|              0
|          19.62|              1|          19.62
|          19.62|            inf|          29.43
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter whether the object is thrown upwards or downwards
Enter U for upwards and D for downwards
d
Enter the distance of the object and the ground
10
------------------------------------------------------------------
|       distance|           time|       Velocity|
------------------------------------------------------------------
|              0|              0|              0|
|          19.62|              1|          19.62|
|          19.62|            inf|          29.43|
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

As you can see the final time is wrong, because you divide by 0, because these lines :

```
     final_time = final_distance / 2 / (0 + final_velocity);
     final_velocity = velocity + magnitute * time;
```

must be exchanged to have

```
     final_velocity = velocity + magnitute * time;
     final_time = final_distance / 2 / (0 + final_velocity);
```

but why do you add *velocity* rather than to have `final_velocity =  magnitute * time;` ?

After that (using `final_velocity = velocity + magnitute * time;`) :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -Wall c.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter whether the object is thrown upwards or downwards
Enter U for upwards and D for downwards
D
Enter the distance of the object and the ground
10
------------------------------------------------------------------
|       distance|           time|       Velocity|
------------------------------------------------------------------
|              0|              0|              0|
|          19.62|              1|          19.62|
|          19.62|       0.333333|          29.43|
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

As I said you do not need a loop, to get the exact results (still without friction) do  `time = sqrt(2 * distance / magnitute)` and `final_velocity = magnitute * time;`

You only manage the downwards case, you have to manage the upward case too.